# LINQ condition inside where to filter

Tags: c#, linq

Im using ASP MVC, I have this LINQ to get employees DTR:

```
 IEnumerable<DatatablesViewModel> viewmodel = 
     (from a in db.tHREmployees
      join b in db.tTADTRs on a.EmpID equals b.EmpID
      join c in db.tHRJobGrades on a.JobGrdID equals c.JobGrdID
      join d in db.tTAShifts on b.ShftID equals d.ShftID
      join e in db.tTADays on b.DayID equals e.DayID
      where (b.LogDt >= PeriodDates.FromDt && b.LogDt <= PeriodDates.ToDt)
      select new DatatablesViewModel
      {
          EmpID = a.EmpID,
          Name = a.LastNm + ", " + a.FirstNm + ", " + a.MiddleNm,
          JobGradeDesc = c.JobGrdDesc,
          ShftNm = d.ShftNm,
          DayType = e.DayNm,
          LogDT = b.LogDt,
          LogIn = b.LogIn,
          LogOut = b.LogOut,
          Absent = b.AbsDay,
          Work = b.WorkHr,
          Late = b.LateHr,
          Overtime = b.OTHr,
          Undertime = b.OTHr,
          Nightdiff = b.NDHr,
          NightPrem = b.NPHr,
          ApprovedOT = b.AppOT,
          ApprovedOB = b.AppOB,
          ApprovedCoa = b.AppCOA,
          ApprovedCs = b.AppCS,
          Exception = b.ExcptStatus
      }).OrderBy(x => x.EmpID);
```

In my view i have dropdown menu that has employee names with 'ALL' option. 
I want to add a condition inside 'where' in above code somthing like:

```
if(parameter.selectedEmp != "ALL"){
Where(x => x.EmpID == param.CustomParam_EmpID) <-- add this filter
```

}

I want to select only what is needed in my query to avoid delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add it in the `Where` clause directly. The `IEnumerable` and your LINQ query are only evaluated once you start to iterate through the collection. You could simply do something like this:

```
var relevantVMObjects = 
 (from a in db.tHREmployees
  join b in db.tTADTRs on a.EmpID equals b.EmpID
  join c in db.tHRJobGrades on a.JobGrdID equals c.JobGrdID
  join d in db.tTAShifts on b.ShftID equals d.ShftID
  join e in db.tTADays on b.DayID equals e.DayID
  where (b.LogDt >= PeriodDates.FromDt && b.LogDt <= PeriodDates.ToDt)
  select new DatatablesViewModel
  {
      EmpID = a.EmpID,
      Name = a.LastNm + ", " + a.FirstNm + ", " + a.MiddleNm,
      JobGradeDesc = c.JobGrdDesc,
      ShftNm = d.ShftNm,
      DayType = e.DayNm,
      LogDT = b.LogDt,
      LogIn = b.LogIn,
      LogOut = b.LogOut,
      Absent = b.AbsDay,
      Work = b.WorkHr,
      Late = b.LateHr,
      Overtime = b.OTHr,
      Undertime = b.OTHr,
      Nightdiff = b.NDHr,
      NightPrem = b.NPHr,
      ApprovedOT = b.AppOT,
      ApprovedOB = b.AppOB,
      ApprovedCoa = b.AppCOA,
      ApprovedCs = b.AppCS,
      Exception = b.ExcptStatus
  }).OrderBy(x => x.EmpID);

 if(parameter.selectedEmp != "ALL")
      relevantVMObjects = relevantVMObjects.Where(x => x.EmpID == param.CustomParam_EmpID);
 IEnumerable<DatatablesViewModel> viewmodel = relevantVMObjects;
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm a newbie using LINQ i thought the data is instantly get to database once linq query was called. i confirmed that using MSSQL profiler and i putting a breakpoint in debug mode.

Comment: It would only be evaluated immediately if you use one of the translator methods like `ToList()` or `ToArray()`. Something to keep in mind if you ever come across the issue of changing data related to a LINQ query which throws the "access to modified closure" exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `OR` condition

```
string selectedEmp=parameter.selectedEmp;
IEnumerable<DatatablesViewModel> viewmodel = 
     (from a in db.tHREmployees
      join b in db.tTADTRs on a.EmpID equals b.EmpID
      join c in db.tHRJobGrades on a.JobGrdID equals c.JobGrdID
      join d in db.tTAShifts on b.ShftID equals d.ShftID
      join e in db.tTADays on b.DayID equals e.DayID
      where (b.LogDt >= PeriodDates.FromDt && b.LogDt <= PeriodDates.ToDt) &&
      (selectedEmp != "ALL" || a.EmpID == param.CustomParam_EmpID)
 select new DatatablesViewModel
      {
           ...
      }
```